# Check if IE Browser - .NET

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, validation, browser

I have my SiteMaster.cs file and I'd like to check if the client browser is using IE to access my site.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thank you

Michael

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check for `Request.UserAgent`. [This site](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/msie-history.html) has a list of user agent string for different versions of IE

Answer (score 9):

[Request.Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser.aspx) gives you the browser details for the current http request.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of browser detection, Feature detection should be used, you can use [mordernizer](http://www.modernizr.com/) for feature detection